# cc command does not work to create object file

Tags: c, makefile

I'm trying to create a makefile that runs a basic Hello World file seen here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

And my makefile:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -g

helloworld: helloworld.o
    cc -o helloworld helloworld.o

clean:
    rm helloworld helloworld.o
```

I keep getting an error that fails to run cc -Wall -g -c -o helloworld.o helloworld.c. I looked at another stack overflow that says that cc may not be installed? But I understand that cc is just the c compiler but I usually use gcc(which cc is an alias of) to compile the file without makefile but even when I use gcc in the makefile I still get an error. Here is the entire error:

```
C:\test>make -f makefile.mk
cc -Wall -g   -c -o helloworld.o helloworld.c
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cc -Wall -g -c -o helloworld.o helloworld.c, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [helloworld1.o] Error 2
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: You're on Windows.  Did you install a compiler?  It doesn't come with it.

Comment: Are some of these helpful? [Posts containing 'makefile createprocess' - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Makefile+CreateProcess)

Comment: Yes I've installed gcc @MarkTolonen

Comment: Then is it on the PATH environement?  Can you just run `cc` or `gcc` from the command prompt?

Comment: yes i can run gcc but cc doesn't seem to work @MarkTolonen. I've also tried doing cc=gcc in the makefile but that doesn't seem to fix it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a built-in rule that make provides for you, to compile a C source file into an object file.  You can tell this, because you didn't write any rule telling make how to compile an object file (you have a rule telling make how to *link* an already-built object file into an executable), so you know that, since make found a rule, it's using one of its built-in rules.

The built-in rules use built-in variables to control them.  The [list of built-in variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html) is described in the GNU make manual.

If you examine the list of built-in variables, you'll see that the name of the C compiler is controlled by the `CC` variable in GNU make (please keep in mind that makefiles, like virtually all POSIX-based tools, which `make` definitely is, **ARE** case-sensitive!!  The variable `cc` is just as surely a different variable from `CC` as the variable `foo` is from `bar`).

So, add this to your makefile and hopefully it will work:

```
CC = gcc
```

Write your makefile like this:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -g

helloworld: helloworld.o
        $(CC) -o helloworld helloworld.o

clean:
        rm helloworld helloworld.o
```

Comment: When you say "didn't work", do you mean that make still printed the command `cc` in the compile line even after you changed the variable?  Or do you mean that it printed `gcc` in the compile line but it still failed with the same error that it couldn't find the file specified?

Comment: @RichardDesouza Did you understand that `CC` **must** be upper case?

Comment: And did you replace `cc -o helloworld helloworld.o` by `$(CC) -o helloworld helloworld.o`?

Comment: If you still get `cc` in the output of the compile of the `.o` then you must have done something wrong.  I will duplicate the entire makefile you've provided with my addition so it's clear what you need to do.

Comment: Yes that works actually sorry for the late reply. Neglected to change cc to a CC variable instead. Thank you so much for the help!